# Using a XGBoost model that was fitted on a database to make predictions on a new database

Tags: python, database, machine-learning, regression, xgboost

I have a database that I have split into train and test datasets, fitted a XGBoost model on the train set, and made predictions using the fitted model on the test set. so far everything is good.

Now if I save the fitted model and want to use it on a completely new dataset to make predictions, what should my new database look like?

Does it have to contain the exact number of features?

Does a categorical feature have to have the same categories in both databases?

Comment: It has to have the same number of features. The model will make predictions regardless of what categories the values are only if it has the same number/type of features, but you would want to make your new data to have the same format as your training data if you want correct predictions.

Comment: @DKDK so does that kind of mean to have the exact number of categories for the categorical features? because I need to end up with same number of columns after I do label encoding. So for example, if I have a color feature with 4 colors, that will create 4 columns from that feature. so if my new database has 5 colors instead of 4, it will create 5 new columns, hence my number of input features would change. please let me know if I'm mistaken here or not. Best Regards.

Comment: You will have to input the exact same number of categories for the categorical features. If your current data for prediction has different format from the training set, reformat is before you input it to the model. If you think about it, the whole point of making the xgboost or any machine learning model is to make a viable prediction from a fixed number of categories.

Comment: @DKDK Thanks so much for your help. It was a very insightful comment and made the whole thing a lot more clearer for me

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory & methodology.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you are using one-hot encoding for lets say the color-feature?

So technically to avoid extra or new features in the test-data, you should form the feature-vector using train+test data.

1. Do one-hot encoding/featurization on the whole set of training+testing data. Now separate out `training-dataset` and `testing-dataset`.
2. Lets say [v1, v2, v3... vn] are the list of feature-names from train+test data.
3. Now form the training-data using this feature-name. As expected the feature-column corresponding to 5th color in the training-data would all be zero `and THATS FINE`
4. Use this same features-list for the test-data, now you shouldnt have any discrepancies in terms of new features coming up.

Hope that clarifies.